does a logical rule with more dependencies infringe upon a logical rule with less depencies?
Patented Method and process:
If (A) and (B) happen, then (X) and (Y) always happen.

Competitor's potential infringer:
1. If (A), (B), and (C) happen, then (X) and (Y) happens.
2. If only (A) and (B) happen, then only (X) happens.

Is there any first principle way to determine if the competitor's version indeed infringes upon the first patented method and process?

A rule, by itself, is not a step in a method claim. It’s hard to answer unless put in to a hypothetical strep of action.
